# A linearly dependent subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Once again, I have a linear algebra question, this one goes as follows:

if $A$ is a linearly dependent subset of $\Bbb R^n$ then the dimension of the  subspace spanned by $A$ is strictly less than $|A|$

I have an idea for an argument for this question however I am having trouble expressing precisely.

**Idea**:
Since $A$ is a linearly dependent subset of $\Bbb R^n$ there must exist at least one $a \in A$  such that $a$ could be written as a linear combination of the remaining vectors in $A$. If we remove all such $a$ from $A$ will would obtain a subset of $A$ where all the vectors in the subset would be linearly  independent, and would span the same subspace spanned by $A$ and thus be a basis for  the subspace and since it contains less elements then $A$. The dimension of the subspace would be less than |$A$|. After all the dimension of a vector space is equal to the number of vectors in any basis.

Any idea on how to express this more concisely and precisely?

Comment: This is true only if the set $A$ is finite. Your argument is good.

Comment: @egreg How would It express this more concisely and with the use of mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is good, but I'd explain it more briefly.

1. The dimension of a (finitely generated) space is the minimum cardinality of a spanning set.
2. If $A$ is linearly dependent, then there exists $a\in A$ such that $a\in\operatorname{Span}(A\setminus\{a\})$, so that $\operatorname{Span}(A)=\operatorname{Span}(A\setminus\{a\})$.
3. The minimum cardinality of a spanning set is at most $|A\setminus\{a\}|$, which is less than $|A|$.